# TCPDF with colorbox

Tags: php, colorbox, tcpdf

I am trying to generate a pdf document inside the colorbox using tcpdf but unable to do so. When opened without colorbox it opens perfectly but inside colorbox it opens like, what could be the issue??

```
%PDF-1.7 %���� 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /LastModified (D:20141204163246+05'30') /Resources 2 0 R /MediaBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /CropBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /BleedBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /TrimBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /ArtBox [0.000000 0.000000 595.276000 841.890000] /Contents 7 0 R /Rotate 0 /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Annots [ 5 0 R ] /PZ 1 >> endobj 7 0 obj <> stream x��][s�H~�WtվL�L���x�u���LmM����k��q���QK6 �ݲE�2A��������9,5��A���џ��1<����2B�_SD&��>�~�!��dN��M����C�yU�����m+�P �3�$���*m(��b&�u��v�@�  :C[6�   �B)L�4�#I%ֱ9��(�����R<s�����sH���O��� �Z��0S��O��c�59Oa�a���O���6�Q\�&��*�  ��� �~�l����l�`�J��n=Wf�Ѭ����W��Э��r6�����������Dûr�J�y��j����d�� QA����$>j���ŅR#--�w�V��=?$h�N;�-�_]ӝ�|���Ȁ�$Y�P��q~�I��j���v%Š1L�\�kk^��,�7,C���3���Ihf��w-��ft4�R[�E���[4�����M�'��Bћ��iM(N���q�V��U>,���g`#�{��A$:���aY�ќ�f�SJ-��u���A�)��і�[��F�������a��{g�M��a����"O�1�G��Bb*݅dsW��)�[����y�v�;?a4��Cp����.wt�s�`  q���R��� ^`r�
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Colorbox's iframe property, instead of trying to open the PDF as ajax, which the browser is treating as text.  Example:

`$('a[href$=".pdf"]').colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    width: '90%',
    height: '90%'
});`